# I want to get the name that is in the 1st place in a list

Tags: python, list

I can't find a specific solution to my problem so I'm opening this question. I have a list,

```
diamonds = [40, 21, 8, 4, 25]
names = ['The maze', 'Plane', 'skin', 'tp', 'hemlet']
s = sorted(zip(diamonds, names), reverse=True)[:3]
print(s)
```

but I would like to get the name that is in the 0, 1 and 2 place. On the net I find that the reverse, get the place from a name. Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: What is the sorting criteria? What is the desired output?

Comment: The question explains essentialy nothing, the code does not run (as the `diamonds` items don't exist) and it doesn't specify what the result *should* be. The post states that "it has a list" but the code snippet has 3 different lists.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see that, I just edited the question. In my output, I would just like to have the names of the first 3 in the list, in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the names, then you can just pick the name from the tuples you created:

```py
s =[item[1] for item in sorted(zip(diamonds, names), reverse=True)[:3]]
```

I get the output:

```
['The maze', 'hemlet', 'Plane']
```